# temporary variable in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

this is my item.py

```
class SampleItem(Item):
    title = Field()
    link = Field()
    link = Field()
    code = Field()
```

and supposedly I want something in my test.py to have a temporary variable like

```
   loc_Con = hxs.select('/tr/td[2]/span/span/span') #for country
   loc_Reg = hxs.select('/tr/td[2]/span/span') #for region
   loc_Loc = hxs.select('//tr[3]/td[2]/span/span') #for local
   items = []
   for titles in titles:
   item = somethingItem()
   temp[1] = loc_Con.select('text()').extract()
   temp[2] = loc_Reg.select('text()').extract()
   temp[3] = loc_Loc.select('text()').extract()
   temp[1] = temp[1][0] if temp1 else ""
   temp[2] = temp[2][0] if temp2 else ""
   temp[3] = temp[3][0] if temp3 else ""
   item["code"] = "{temp[1]}-{temp[2]}-{temp[3]}".format(temp[1], 
                                                         temp[2],
                                                         temp[3])
```

what should I do so that I don't have to add temp[1] = Field in the items.py

Comment: Your code looks strange. Your `SampleItem` class has 2 fields names "link". For `temp[1] = loc_Con.select('text()').extract()`, `temp` is not defined, neither are `temp1`, `temp2` and `temp3`. Can you post your real code? and perhaps explain what you want to change so that we can help you modify/fix it

Comment: sorry about that.. that should be a single 
link = Field() in there  
my point is that i don't want to add temp1 = Field() in my item.py so that it will not be written to my csv file. I want to have a temporary variable storing data before I join temp[1], temp[2], temp[3] to item ["code"]

Comment: You don't need to. `item["code"]=...` will be assigned a new string value created from the 3 variables, but these variables won't be referenced anymore after the loop, the value of `item["code"]` will be "independent"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can define whatever temporary variables in your loop to compute the string value you need for `item["code"]`. `item["code"]` will then hold a new string value, via `.format()`, independently from the temporary variables.

```
loc_Con = hxs.select('/tr/td[2]/span/span/span') #for country
loc_Reg = hxs.select('/tr/td[2]/span/span') #for region
loc_Loc = hxs.select('//tr[3]/td[2]/span/span') #for local
items = []
for titles in titles:
   item = somethingItem()
   temp1 = loc_Con.select('text()').extract()
   temp2 = loc_Reg.select('text()').extract()
   temp3 = loc_Loc.select('text()').extract()
   temp1 = temp1[0] if temp1 else ""
   temp2 = temp2[0] if temp2 else ""
   temp3 = temp3[0] if temp3 else ""
   item["code"] = "{0}-{1}-{2}".format(temp1, 
                                       temp2,
                                       temp3)
```

So no need to add any special `temp[1] = Field()`.

Comment: that's cool! So I was already near with what I came up... Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, very close. Also, `.format()` syntax can sometimes be less easy than, in your case let's say `item["code"] = "-".join([temp1, temp2, temp3])` (joining list elements with a "-")

Comment: will it produce the same output?

Comment: In your case it should yes. There are many ways of achieving the same string results in Python

Comment: Probably. But I just started using yesterday to explore usages in scrapy so I just stick with the basics.